# How do the stats convert into a percental value?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

In the character overview you can see your stats like Critical Hit Rate.
For maxing out dps, healing and damage reduction, I would like to know how I can convert those numbers into a percentage.

This would be interesting for those values:

- Critical Hit Rate
- Determination
- Defense
- Parry
- Magic Defense
- Attack Magic Potency
- Healing Magic Potency
- Spell Speed maybe?
- Skill Speed maybe?

Comment: This is not a bad question, but unfortunately the way the game is designed, there isn't a way to give you a good answer to this question.  Not only are the formulas unknown, but as coldReactive said, the numbers for enemies would need to be data mined as well.  There are too many unknowns to give you any good information, but I'm sure there are forums or other sites that may have people that are trying to find that information.  Also remember, a lot of stats are affected by level too, so that doesn't help find the answer either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's currently no in-game way to show what damage increase or percentage each point of rating gives you, unless you logged a ton of hits at various stat values and mathed it out.  Fortunately, Nemekh and the Akh Morning team have already done this for you with a [chart showing all the stat breakpoints at every level](https://www.akhmorning.com/allagan-studies/stats/).

Note that the most beneficial stat for you will vary depending on your class and class's mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

They don't, because you have to take in account the target's stats for the opposing stats. Unless we can data mine the enemies and get every single one's stats, and you can make an add-on to show these variables when in battle with that specific enemy (Which, by the way, would be considered cheating to be honest, since it could work in PVP theoretically.)

Parry by the way was changed in Heavensward so that it no longer is raised by Strength and Dexterity.

Answer (score 1):

These are known as statweights.

Typically they are expressed as a ratio of how much X stat (SS, Crit, Det) is worth in Main Stat (STR/VIT/DEX/INT). For example Crit is weighted at `0.387`, so it takes around `2.6` crit on your gear to be equal to a point of STR or DEX.

Dervy is one of the people who crunches out the stat weights for us (thanks) using mathematical models: https://dervyxiv.wordpress.com/stat-weights/

Ariyala's Toolkit: http://ffxiv.ariyala.com/ has a gear calculator that uses the statweights to find out what's the best stuff to wear.

For "toughness" it's pretty much how much VIT you have in practice.

For healing, it's mostly preference, but I've found that no one stat is more important than the others. There's a maximum of piety that you want (a little, not a lot).

For endgame raiding, you're looking at your DPS output for all classes rather than your ability to tank or heal, since you don't need a lot of toughness or healing throughput in order to actually do it.

Comment: Those are stat weights, which is not what he's after. He doesn't want to know "I have 260 crit, how much STR is that worth?" he wants to know "I have 260 crit, how big of an increase to my chance to crit do I get from that?"